# Angular 2 Observables POST headers

Tags: angular, rxjs

Invoking POST request like below in Angular 2 via Observables

```
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token);
this.http.post(environment.API_ENDPOINT + 'user/register?name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&os_version=' + os_version
            + '&os=' + os + '&device_id=' + device_id,
            { headers }).map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

The problem is the headers are not recognized by the Python/tornado Server.When I debugged the headers and other info has "\n".

Log

```
 <URL>/user/register?name=cool2&email=cool2@gmail.com&password=qwerty1233456&os_version=xyz&os=xyz&device_id=xyz, 
body: b'{\n  "method": null,\n  
 "headers": {\n    "Authorization": [\n      "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNTc0Y2UzMzI4YjEyZDgyMWEwMmFkMDllIiwiZXhwIjoxNDkyNTc1NzA3fQ.VkHHr15GQWkZqBllX5I3DUuaEPYOmFYOx92qKZfw8Vs"\n    ]\n  },
\n  "body": null,\n  "url": null,\n  "withCredentials": null,\n  "responseType": null\n}'
```

Comment: Have you checked the answers? If some of them was helpful, you could mark it as accepted, otherwise write a comment about why it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `http.post()` with wrong parameters - you are sending them to your backend as a request body - the second parameter. See

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#update

You should call it like this:

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
const requestBody = { ... }; // any kind of object
this.http.post(url, requestBody, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written wrong post api call in your angular service.
it should be `http.post(ApiUri, body, options)`

below is the code sample which i had used in my service.ts

> user-service.ts

```
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Jsonp, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Config } from '../index';
import { AuthCookie } from '../services/auth-cookies-handler';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp, private _http: Http, private _authCookie: AuthCookie) { }

    public jsonHeaders(): Headers {
        let headers: Headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        let userInfo: any = JSON.parse(this._authCookie.getAuth());
        if (userInfo && (this._authCookie.getAuth() != '{"user":"GuestUser"}')) 
        {
            headers.append('Authtoken', 'Basic ' + userInfo.authtoken);
        }
        return headers;
    }

    saveUser(user: User): Observable<User> {

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.jsonHeaders(), method: 'post' });

        let body = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')); //--in your case--
        //let body = user;

        return this._http.post(Config.API + 'users', body, options)
                .map((res: Response) => {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.